# How to control the length of numbers after the radix point?

Tags: r

I was using function 'stat.desc' of package 'pastecs' to analyze data 'Michelson' in package 'Mass'. Despite I set options(digits=3), it still came back too long a result. Is there any way to revise this?

```
options(digits = 3,scipen=200)
stat.desc(michelson$Speed)
```

And the result is like:

```
 nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range 
    100.0000       0.0000       0.0000     620.0000    1070.0000     450.0000 
         sum       median         mean      SE.mean CI.mean.0.95          var 
  85240.0000     850.0000     852.4000       7.9011      15.6774    6242.6667 
     std.dev     coef.var 
     79.0105       0.0927
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `?stat.desc` there is no mechanism for changing the number of digits. If you look at the code to that function there's no class attribute assigned to the result. If you look at `print.default` which is what I think would be doing any display to the console you see a digits parameter described in the Arguments section:

> digits
> a non-null value for digits specifies the minimum number of significant digits to be printed in values.

You apparently thought that it would instead be controlling the maximum number of digits. Sorry. If you want the number of digits to display with fewer digits, you need to use functions that allow that level of control.

Unfortunately for this exchange of ideas, you have not offered a reproducible example, so I thought I would look at the example in the help page. That, however, didn't seem to fit your problem:

```
 op <- options(digits = 3,scipen=200)
 data(marbio)
 stat.desc(marbio[,13:16])
#---------------------------------------------
              Nauplii     Oithona Acanthaires Cladocerans
nbr.val         68.00      68.000      68.000       68.00
nbr.null         0.00       0.000       8.000       45.00
nbr.na           0.00       0.000       0.000        0.00
min              3.00      39.000       0.000        0.00
max            636.00    7792.000      52.000      200.00
range          633.00    7753.000      52.000      200.00
sum           9018.00  105159.000     987.000      394.00
median         104.00    1228.000      12.000        0.00
mean           132.62    1546.456      14.515        5.79
SE.mean         12.54     155.439       1.459        3.04
CI.mean.0.95    25.03     310.258       2.912        6.06
var          10696.48 1642971.655     144.731      626.76
std.dev        103.42    1281.785      12.030       25.04
coef.var         0.78       0.829       0.829        4.32
#------
 options(op)
```

So if you can assign the output to a named object and then run `dput` on it you would be able to cut and paste that output into the body of your question. (Do NOT use comments for that purpose.)